# Python Django URL render incorrect template

Tags: python, django, url

Sorry for my english.

Have some problem with rendering template in Dgango.
URLs is correct, but incorrect template returns.

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI4Qg.png)

So URL is correct, but it return me TASK-LIST, i expect TASK-DETAIL.
Can't find the problem by myself..

And the project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDdqT.png)

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Task
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    num_tasks = Task.objects.all().count()
    num_workers = Task.objects.all().filter(status='N').count()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'num_tasks':num_tasks,'num_workers':num_workers},)


class TaskListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Task
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['some_data'] = 'This is just some data'
        return context


class TaskDetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = Task
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse #Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL patterns


# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('A', 'Active'),
    ('R', 'Ready'),
    ('H', 'Hold'),
    ('N', 'Dont start')
    )
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, help_text = 'Укажите наименование задачи')
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    worker = models.CharField(max_length = 200, help_text = 'Укажите сотрудника, которому назначена задача')
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'N')

    class Meta():
        ordering = ('date_start',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**URLS.PY in App path:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('tasks/', views.TaskListView.as_view(), name = 'tasks'),
    path('task/<int:pk>', views.TaskDetailView.as_view(), name = 'task-detail'),
]
```

**URLS.PY in PROJECT APP**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from FirstPart import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('FirstPart.urls')),
    path('FirstPart/', include('FirstPart.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/FirstPart/', permanent=True)),
]
```

**BASE_GENERIC.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  {% block title %}<title>Other topic</title>{% endblock %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
        {% block navbar %}
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'tasks' %}">Task list</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
       {% endblock %}

       <div class="container-fluid">

           {% block pagination %}
             {% if is_paginated %}
                 <div class="pagination">
                     <span class="page-links">
                         {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                             <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                         {% endif %}
                         <span class="page-current">
                             Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                         </span>
                         {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                             <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                         {% endif %}
                     </span>
            {% endif %}
           {% endblock %}
             {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**TASK-LIST.HTML**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Task List</h1>

    {% if task_list %}
    <ul>

      {% for task in task_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ task.get_absolute_url }}">{{ task.task_name}}</a> ({{task.worker}}) ({{task.status}})
      </li>
      {% endfor %}

    </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>There are no tasks on the board.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**TASK-DETAIL.HTML**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Title: {{ task.task_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>task_name:</strong> <a href="">{{ task.task_name }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>date_start:</strong> {{ task.date_start }}</p>
  <p><strong>date_end:</strong> {{ task.date_end }}</p>
  <p><strong>worker:</strong> {{ task.worker }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TaskDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Task
```

please change your `TaskDetailView` and check